# A Good and SIMPLE Measure of Randomness

Tags: algorithm, random

What is the best algorithm to take a long sequence of integers (say 100,000 of them) and return a measurement of how random the sequence is?

The function should return a single result, say 0 if the sequence is not all all random, up to, say 1 if perfectly random. It can give something in-between if the sequence is somewhat random, e.g. 0.95 might be a reasonably random sequence, whereas 0.50 might have some non-random parts and some random parts.

If I were to pass the first 100,000 digits of Pi to the function, it should give a number very close to 1.  If I passed the sequence 1, 2, ... 100,000 to it, it should return 0.

This way I can easily take 30 sequences of numbers, identify how random each one is, and return information about their relative randomness.

Is there such an animal?

…..

Update 24-Sep-2019: [Google may have just ushered in an era of quantum supremacy](https://www.theverge.com/2019/9/23/20879485/google-quantum-supremacy-qubits-nasa) says:

> "Google’s quantum computer was reportedly able to solve a calculation — proving the randomness of numbers produced by a random number generator — in 3 minutes and 20 seconds that would take the world’s fastest traditional supercomputer, Summit, around 10,000 years. This effectively means that the calculation cannot be performed by a traditional computer, making Google the first to demonstrate quantum supremacy."

So obviously there is an algorithm to "prove" randomness. Does anyone know what it is? Could this algorithm also provide a measure of randomness?

Comment: Possible starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_tests

Comment: I'm surprised to see that there are actually algorithms that claim to be able to test randomness. Perhaps I have a different definition of random than you are talking about, but from a logical viewpoint this should be mathematically impossible. Even if you pass in 100K digits that are all 4's it is completely feasible that it was generated randomly. Reading some of the articles it looks like they are more designed to evaluate the distribution than actual randomness.

Comment: Found this article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_randomness) that explains the difference between statistical and true randomness that cleared it up for me. Interesting...

Comment: The odds against a true random sequence continuing to be the same number grows so exponentially fast, that it becomes effectively impossible for 100K digits that are the same.

Comment: @lkessler - the odds of a true random sequence consisting entirely of a single digit (e.g. 100,000 fours) are the same as for any other particular series of digits.  Since you're only examining one particular sequence, there's no way to know whether it was generated by a truly random process or not.  And so you're left with statistical randomness.

Comment: jbourque: That is true, but the difference is that the likeliness (a statistical thing) of a series that is that long having any predicable pattern is so infinitesimally small that the expectation would be near 100% that it was NOT produced by a random generator. My question is to find a measurement of how random a series is. A series of 100,000 fours is NOT random, whether is was produced by a random number generator or not.

Comment: @JohnFx I think what he means by "measure of randomness" is, "_given the history of the number sequence, how easy is it to predict the next number in the sequence_".  0 means it's obvious what number should be next (as in a string of 4's), and 1 means it's completely unobvious (ie there's no recognizable pattern).  In that sense PI (or sqrt(2)) are very random (although if you know the formula or how the number string is found then it is completely deterministic).

Comment: @jbourque I disagree. ANY number (pattern or not) has an equally tiny chance in a random sequence. Now, PREDICTING that a random number generator would create that value (or any other) is extremely unlikely.

Comment: @JohnFx you can definitely test to see if a sequence of numbers was likely generated by a random number generator vs some other process.   there are good tests for "likely random" vs "likely not".   ... you can only produce a likelihood, but of course there's never a way to be sure.   these tests are how they check to see if a cryptographic hash, for example, is decent or not.

Comment: Ha ha! I didn't even realize that I updated my question EXACTLY 10 years after I first posted it!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It can be done this way:

CAcert Research Lab does [a Random Number Generator Analysis](http://www.cacert.at/random/).

[Their results page](http://www.cacert.at/cgi-bin/rngresults) evaluates each random sequence using 7 tests (Entropy, Birthday Spacing, Matrix Ranks, 6x8 Matrix Ranks, Minimum Distance, Random Spheres, and the Squeeze). Each test result is then color coded as one of "No Problems", "Potentially deterministic" and "Not Random".

So a function can be written that accepts a random sequence and does the 7 tests.
If any of the 7 tests are "Not Random" then the function returns a 0. If all of the 7 tests are "No Problems", then it returns a 1. Otherwise, it can return some number in-between based on how many tests come in as "Potentially Deterministic".

The only thing missing from this solution is the code for the 7 tests.

Comment: That results page is a treasure trove of pseudorandom number generators. It also shows a pretty high score for the digits of pi (search for PiDigits).

Of course, the evaluation of the digits of pi as "likely nondeterministic" reveals a fundamental weakness in our terminology.

Comment: You could start here: [https://www.fourmilab.ch/random/](https://www.fourmilab.ch/random/)

Answer (score 21):

Your question answers itself. "If I were to pass the first 100,000 digits of Pi to the function, it should give a number very close to 1", except the digits of Pi are not random numbers so if your algorithm does not recognise a very specific sequence as being non-random then it's not very good.

The problem here is there are many types of non random-ness:-
eg. "121,351,991,7898651,12398469018461" or "33,27,99,3000,63,231" or even "14297141600464,14344872783104,819534228736,3490442496" are definitely not random.

I think what you need to do is identify the aspects of randomness that are important to you-
distribution, distribution of digits, lack of common factors, the expected number of primes, Fibonacci and other "special" numbers etc. etc.

PS. The Quick and Dirty (and very effective) test of randomness does the file end up roughly the same size after you gzip it.

Comment: I am puzzled how you can say that the digits of Pi or not random. It may be true that Pi's randomness within its first hundred million digits might not be as effective for certain applications like data encryption as some other random generators (See: http://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2005/04/050427094258.htm ), but I've never seen anything that has ever declared the digits of Pi to be non-random.

Comment: +1 for "identify the aspects of randomness that are important to you".  If it's random then it will pass tests for randomness; but the converse doesn't hold -- there's no test that can verify randomness, for example, one could have very strong correlations between elements far apart and one would generally have to test explicitly for this.  In fact, I like this so much I'll write it as my own answer...

Comment: pi is not a random sequence of digits, its a very spcific sequence of digits - its long and does not contain any significant repititions - but it is always the same sequence.

Comment: re pi: The link on statistical randomness that JohnFx points out clears up the issue about pi. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474382/a-good-and-simple-measure-of-randomness

Comment: @lkessler:  What are you using the random numbers for?  If it's for encryption, as you suggest, then you've lost as soon as the cryptologist realizes you're using sequences from pi.

Comment: I don't plan to use the digits from Pi. I just included that as an example. The goal is that we want to be able to classify series of numbers by the degree of randomness for various uses.

Comment: Would like to point out that the "gzip" method is actually pretty good. The dictionary building algorithm used is very good at picking up patterns you didnt know were there.

Comment: See "Are the Digits of Pi Random?"  http://www.lbl.gov/Science-Articles/Archive/pi-random.html

Comment: thanks for quick and dirty gzip - love it...  and this is an answer from 7+ years ago - thanks

Answer (score 9):

You could try to zip-compress the sequence. The better you succeed the less random the sequence is.

Thus, heuristic randomness = length of zip-code/length of original sequence

Comment: Thanks, I was inspired by Kolmogorov complexity. According to Kolmogorov a sequence is random if it cannot be produced by an algorithm which is shorter than the sequence. For instance, PI is not random because it can be produced by a short algorithm.

Comment: Well,  zip cannot discover the non-randomness in PI. Since PI is not rational it does not repeat itself, and repetitions is  what zip can discover. However, it takes only 3.32 = log(10)/log(2) bit to represent a digit (0...9) in binary. 3.32 bit is 41.5% of a an 8 bit byte. If you did compress 1GB of PI I guess zip would reach 41.5%

Comment: @ragnarius pi is, by definition, statistically random.

Comment: @data i'm guessing you used decimal digits.   zip just found a better representation.   treating the digits as a single long number and using a base-256 sequence of bytes instead.... you'll see far less compression in pi.

Answer (score 8):

As others have pointed out, you can't directly calculate how random a sequence is but there are several statistical tests that you could use to increase your *confidence* that a sequence is or isn't random.

The [DIEHARD suite](http://www.stat.fsu.edu/pub/diehard/) is the de facto standard for this kind of testing but it neither returns a single value nor is it simple.

[ENT - A Pseudorandom Number Sequence Test Program](http://www.fourmilab.ch/random/), is a simpler alternative that combines 5 different tests.  The website explains how each of these tests works.

If you really need just a single value, you could pick one of the 5 ENT tests and use that.  The [Chi-Squared test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson's_chi-square_test) would probably be the best to use, but that might not meet the definition of simple.

Bear in mind that a single test is not as good as running several different tests on the same sequence.  Depending on which test you choose, it should be good enough to flag up obviously suspicious sequences as being non-random, but might not fail for sequences that superficially appear random but actually exhibit some pattern.

Comment: Don't forget TestU01, which is what the cool kids seem to be using. Also PractRand seems cool.

Answer (score 7):

You can treat you 100.000 outputs as possible outcomes of a random variable and calculate associated entropy of it. It will give you a measure of uncertainty. (Following image is from wikipedia and you can find more information on [Entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28Information_theory%29) there.) Simply:

[image: Entropy formula]

You just need to calculate the frequencies of each number in the sequence. That will give you p(xi) (e.g. If 10 appears 27 times p(10) = 27/L where L is 100.000 for your case.) This should give you the measure of entropy.

Although it will not give you a number between 0 to 1. Still 0 will be minimal uncertainty. However the upper bound will not be 1. You need to normalize the output to achieve that.

Comment: Hmmmm.... so what's the entropy of 111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888889999999999 ?

Comment: To be clear, I think entropy could be useful, but one can't just slap the formula onto the data. In the repeated digits example, although the distribution has high entropy (for the digits 1-9), the difference between adjacent digits has very low entropy (i.e. not random, as one can clearly see). But here again, you're back to defining what you mean by randomness, and testing directly for that feature. (Also, entropy is one of the trickier measures and takes some study to get right, so it's better avoided unless one really needs it.)

Comment: Tom you are right, entropy itself will not work. Actually this a stochastic process and you need to entropy rate of it (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_rate). I do not know how to calculate it. But somehow it needs to have a high entropy as well as some other properties. Your example clear has a high entropy but still the next number in the chain is predictable.

Comment: I disagree. The sequence given is very "random" given the test that we are putting it through. If you instead did an autocorrelation test the sequence would have many peaks and would be deemed not very random. Don't confuse statistical randomness with the idea of a random variable. Statistical randomness is just that, its statistically checking a sequence for randomness based on a chosen test.

Comment: Also, do not assume that the intuitive concept of randomness and what a random variable is one and the same.

Comment: The images link is dead. Please fix it. I'm guessing you had some kind of equation there? Maybe link to a wikipedia graphic?

Answer (score 4):

What you seek doesn't exist, at least not how you're describing it now.

The basic issue is this:
If it's random then it will pass tests for randomness; but the converse doesn't hold -- there's no test that can verify randomness.

For example, one could have very strong correlations between elements far apart and one would generally have to test explicitly for this.  Or one could have a flat distribution but generated in a very non-random way.  Etc, etc.

In the end, you need to decide on what aspects of randomness are important to you, and test for these (as James Anderson describes in his answer).  I'm sure if you think of any that aren't obvious how to test for, people here will help.

Btw, I usually approach this problem from the other side: I'm given some set of data that looks for all I can see to be completely random, but I need to determine whether there's a pattern somewhere.  Very non-obvious, in general.

Answer (score 3):

"How random is this sequence?" is a tough question because fundamentally you're interested in how the sequence was generated. As others have said it's entirely possible to generate sequences that appear random, but don't come from sources that we'd consider random (e.g. digits of pi).

Most randomness tests seek to answer a slightly different questions, which is: "Is this sequence anomalous with respect to a given model?". If you're model is rolling ten sided dice, then it's pretty easy to quantify how likely a sequence is generated from that model, and the digits of pi would not look anomalous. But if your model is "Can this sequence be easily generated from an algorithm?" it becomes much more difficult.

Comment: No, I'm really asking this:  I've got a series of numbers. How random is the series?  I may not know or don't really care how it was generated. I just want to know if it is random or not.

Comment: My point was you have to define random with some sort of model.

Answer (score 3):

I want to emphasize here that the word "random" means not only *identically distributed*, but also *independent of everything else* (including independent of any other choice).

There are numerous "randomness tests" available, including tests that estimate *p-values* from running various statistical probes, as well as tests that estimate *min-entropy*, which is roughly a minimum "compressibility" level of a bit sequence and the most relevant entropy measure for "secure random number generators". There are also various "[randomness extractors](https://peteroupc.github.io/randextract.html)", such as the von Neumann and Peres extractors, that could give you an idea on how much "randomness" you can extract from a bit sequence. However, all these tests and methods can only be more reliable on the first part of this definition of randomness ("identically distributed") than on the second part ("independent").

In general, there is no algorithm that can tell, *from a sequence of numbers alone*, whether the process generated them in an independent and identically distributed way, without knowledge on what that process is. Thus, for example, although you can tell that a given sequence of bits has more zeros than ones, you can't tell whether those bits—

- Were truly generated independently of any other choice, or
- form part of an extremely long periodic sequence that is only "locally random", or
- were simply reused from another process, or
- were produced in some other way,

...without more information on the process. As one important example, the process of a person choosing a password is rarely "random" in this sense since passwords tend to contain familiar words or names, among other reasons.

Also I should discuss the article added to your question in 2019. That article dealt with the task of sampling from the distribution of bit strings generated by pseudorandom quantum circuits, and doing so with a low rate of error (a task specifically designed to be exponentially easier for quantum computers than for classical computers), rather than the task of "verifying" whether a particular sequence of bits (taken out of its context) was generated "at random" in the sense given in this answer. There is an explanation on what exactly this "task" is in a [July 2020 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2007.07872.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

In Computer Vision when analysing textures, the problem of trying to gauge the randomness of  a texture comes up, in order to segment it. This is exactly the same as your question, because you are trying to determine the randomness of a sequence of bytes/integers/floats. The best discussion I could find of image entropy is http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=274518  .

Basically, its the statistical measure of randomness for a sequence of values.

I would also try autocorrelation of the sequence with itself. In the autocorrelation result, if there is no peaks other than the first value that means there is no periodicity to your input.

Answer (score 2):

I would use Claude Shannon’s Information Entropy algorithm.  You can find the calculation on Youtube easily.  I guess it really depends upon why you want this to be measured, and what type of reporting you want to do with the data points you collect.

Comment: I would encourage you to search and add some links to Youtube videos in your answer itself. It will be helpful for the reader.

Answer (score 1):

@JohnFx *"... mathematically impossible."*

poster states: *take a long sequence of integers ...*

Thus, just as limits are used in The Calculus, we can take the value as being the value - the study of Chaotics shows us finite limits may 'turn on themselves' producing tensor fields that provide the illusion of absolute(s), and which can be run as long as there is time and energy. Due to the curvature of space-time, there is no perfection - hence the op's "*... say 1 if perfectly random.*" is a misnomer.

{ **noted**: ample observations on that have been provided - spare me }

According to your position, given two byte[] of a few k, each randomized independently - op could not obtain "a measurement of how random the sequence is" The article at Wiki is informative, and makes definite strides dis-entagling the matter, but

In comparison to classical physics, quantum physics predicts that the properties of a quantum mechanical system depend on the measurement context, i.e. whether or not other system measurements are carried out.

> A team of physicists from Innsbruck,
>   Austria, led by Christian Roos and
>   Rainer Blatt, have for the first time
>   proven in a comprehensive experiment
>   that it is not possible to explain
>   quantum phenomena in non-contextual
>   terms.

Source: Science Daily

Let us consider non-random lizard movements. The source of the stimulus that initiates complex movements in the shed tails of leopard geckos, under your original, corrected hyper-thesis, can never be known. We, the experienced computer scientists, suffer the innocent challenge posed by newbies knowing too well that there - in the context of an un-tainted and pristine mind - are them gems and germinators of feed-forward thinking.

If the thought-field of the original lizard produces a tensor-field ( deal with it folks, this is front-line research in sub-linear physics ) then we could have "the best algorithm to take a long sequence" of civilizations spanning from the Toba Event to present through a Chaotic Inversion". Consider the question whether such a thought-field produced by the lizard, taken independently, is a spooky or knowable.

> "Direct observation of Hardy's paradox
>   by joint weak measurement with an
>   entangled photon pair," authored by
>   Kazuhiro Yokota, Takashi Yamamoto,
>   Masato Koashi and Nobuyuki Imoto from
>   the Graduate School of Engineering
>   Science at Osaka University and the
>   CREST Photonic Quantum Information
>   Project in Kawaguchi City

Source: Science Daily

( considering the spooky / knowable dichotomy )

I know from my own experiments that direct observation weakens the absoluteness of perceptible tensors, distinguishing between thought and perceptible tensors is impossible using only single focus techniques because the perceptible tensor is not the original thought. A fundamental consequence of quantaeus is that only weak states of perceptible tensors can be reliably distinguished from one another without causing a collapse into a unified perceptible tensor. Try it sometime - work on the mainifestation of some desired eventuality, using pure thought. Because an idea has no time or space, it is therefore in-finite. ( not-finite ) and therefore can attain "perfection" - i.e. absoluteness. Just for a hint, start with the weather as that is the easiest thing to influence ( as least as far as is currently known ) then move as soon as can be done to doing a join from the sleep-state to the waking-state with virtually no interruption of sequential chaining.

There is an almost unavoidable blip there when the body wakes up but it is just like when the doorbell rings, speaking of which brings an interesting area of statistical research to funding availability: How many thoughts can one maintain synchronously? I find that duality is the practical working limit, at triune it either breaks on the next thought or doesn't last very long.

Perhaps the work of Yokota et al could reveal the source of spurious net traffic...maybe it's ghosts.

Comment: . . . . . . . . . What?

Answer (score 0):

As per Knuth, make sure you test the low-order bits for randomness, since many algorithms exhibit terrible randomness in the lowest bits.

Answer (score 0):

Although this question is old, it does not seem "solved", so here is my 2 cents, showing that it is still an important problem that can be discussed in simple terms.

Consider password security.

The question was about "long" number sequences, "say 100.000", but does not state what is the criterium for "long". For passwords, 8 characters might be considered long. If those 8 chars were "random", it might be considered a good password, but if it can be easily guessed, a useless password.

Common password rules are to mix upper case, numbers and special characters. But the commonly used "Password1" is still a bad password. (okay, 9-char example, sorry) So how many of the methods of the other answers you apply, you should also check if the password occurs in several dictionaries, including sets of leaked passwords.

But even then, just imagine the rise of a new Hollywood star. This may lead to a new famous name that will be given to newborns, and may become popular as a password, that is not yet in the dictionaries.

If I am correctly informed, it is pretty much impossible to automatically verify that a password selected by a human is random and not derived with an easy to guess algorithm. And also that a good password system should work with computer-generated random passwords.

The conclusion is that there is no method to verify if an 8-char password is random, let alone a good and simple method. And if you cannot verify 8 characters, why would it be easier to verify 100.000 numbers?

The password example is just one example of how important this question of randomness is; think also about encryption. Randomness is the holy grail of security.

Answer (score -2):

Measuring randomness? In order to do so, you should fully understand its meaning. The problem is, if you search the internet you will reach the conclusion that there is a nonconformity concept of randomness. For some people it's one thing, for others it's something else. You'll even find some definitions given through a philosophical perspective. One of the most frequent misleading concepts is to test if "it's random or not random". Randomness is not a "yes" or a "no", it could be anything in between. Although it is possible to measure and quantify "randomness", its concept should remain relative regarding its classification and categorization. So, to say that something is random or not random in an absolute way would be wrong because it's relative and even subjective for that matter. Accordingly, it is also subjective and relative to say that something follows a pattern or doesn't because, what's a pattern? In order to measure randomness, you have to start off by understanding it's mathematical theoretical premise. The premise behind randomness is easy to understand and accept. If all possible outcomes/elements in your sample space have the EXACT same probability of happening than randomness is achieved to it's fullest extent. It's that simple. What is more difficult to understand is linking this concept/premise to a certain sequence/set or a distribution of outcomes of events in order to determine a degree of randomness. You could divide your sample into sets or subsets and they could prove to be relatively random. The problem is that even if they prove to be random by themselves, it could be proven that the sample is not that random if analyzed as a whole. So, in order to analyze the degree of randomness, you should consider the sample as a whole and not subdivided. Conducting several tests to prove randomness will necessarily lead to subjectiveness and redundancy. There are no 7 tests or 5 tests, there is only one. And that test follows the already mentioned premise and thus determines the degree of randomness based on the outcome distribution type or in other words, the outcome frequency distribution type of a given sample. The specific sequence of a sample is not relevant. A specific sequence would only be relevant if you decide to divide your sample into subsets, which you shouldn't, as I already explained. If you consider the variable p(possible outcomes/elements in sample space) and n(number of trials/events/experiments) you will have a number of total possible sequences of (p^n) or (p to the power of n). If we consider the already mentioned premise to be true, any of these possible sequences have the exact same probability of occurring. Because of this, any specific sequence would be inconclusive in order to calculate the "randomness" of a sample. What is essential is to calculate the probability of the outcome distribution type of a sample of happening. In order to do so, we would have to calculate all the sequences that are associated with the outcome distribution type of a sample. So if you consider s=(number of all possible sequences that lead to a outcome distribution type), then s/(p^n) would give you a value between 0 and 1 which should be interpreted as being a measurement of randomness for a specific sample. Being that 1 is 100% random and 0 is 0% random. It should be said that you will never get a 1 or a 0 because even if a sample represents the MOST likely random outcome distribution type it could never be proven as being 100%. And if a sample represents the LEAST likely random outcome distribution type it could never be proven as being 0%. This happens because since there are several possible outcome distribution types, no single one of them can represent being 100% or 0% random. In order to determine the value of variable (s), you should use the same logic used in multinominal distribution probabilities. This method applies to any number of possible outcomes/elements in sample space and to any number of experiments/trials/events. Notice that, the bigger your sample is, the more are the possible outcome frequency distribution types, and the less is the degree of randomness that can be proven by each one of them.
Calculating [s/(n^t)]*100 will give you the probability of the outcome frequency dirtibution type of a set occuring if the source is truly random. The higher the probability the more random your set is. To actually obtain a value of randomness you would have to divide [s/(n^t)] by the highest value [s/(n^t)] of all possible outcome frequency distibution types and multiply by 100.