# How to define your encryption algorithm's strength in terms of bits?

Tags: encryption, bit

I'm in the process of designing an encryption algorithm. The algorithm is symmetric (single key).

How do you measure an algorithms strength in terms of bits? Is the key length the strength of the algorithm?

**EDIT:**

> **Lesson 1**: Don't design an encryption algorithm, AES and others are
> designed and standardized by academics for a reason
>
> **Lesson 2**: An encryption algorithms strength is not measured in bits, key sizes are. An algorithm's strength is determined by its design. In general, an algorithm using a larger key size is harder to brute-force, and thus stronger.

Comment: "I am designing an encryption algorithm " - Don't. Seriously.

Comment: Imagine a 1,048,576-bit run of 1s...

Comment: @Laim E-p: The key is just part of the algorithms you mentioned, there are a lot more in them than keys.

Comment: why is this tagged for c and c++?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, is this for anything serious? If it is, stop right now. Don't do it. Designing algorithms is one of the hardest things in the world. Unless you have years and years of experience breaking ciphers, you will not design anything remotely secure.

AES and RSA serve two very different purposes. The difference is more than just signing. RSA is a public key algorithm. We use it for encryption, key exchange, digital signatures. AES is a symmetric block cipher. We use it for bulk encryption. RSA is very slow. AES is very fast. Most modern cryptosystems use a hybrid approach of using RSA for key exchange, and then AES for the bulk encryption.

Typically when we say "128-bit strength", we mean the size of the key. This is incredibly deceptive though, in that there is much more to the strength of an algorithm than the size of it's key. In other words, just because you have a million bit key, it means nothing.

The strength of an algorithm, is defined both in terms of it's key size, as well as it's resistance to cryptanalytic attacks. We say an algorithm is broken if there exists an attack better than brute force.

So, with AES and a 128-bit key, AES is considered "secure" if there is no attack that less than 2^128 work. If there is, we consider it "broken" (in an academic sense). Some of these attacks (for your searching) include differential cryptanalysis, linear cryptanalysis, and related key attacks.

How we brute force an algorithm also depends on it's type. A symmetric block cipher like AES is brute forced by trying every possible key. For RSA though, the size of the key is the size of the modulus. We don't break that by trying every possible key, but rather factoring. So the strength of RSA then is dependent on the current state of number theory. Thus, the size of the key doesn't always tell you it's actual strength. RSA-128 is horribly insecure. Typically RSA key sizes are 1024-bits+.

DES with a 56-bit key is stronger than pretty much EVERY amateur cipher ever designed.

If you are interested in designing algorithms, you should start by breaking other peoples. Bruce Schenier has a self-study course in cryptanalysis that can get you started: http://www.schneier.com/paper-self-study.html

FEAL is one of the most broken ciphers of all time. It makes for a great starting place of learning block cipher cryptanalysis. The source code is available, and there are countless published papers on it, so you can always "look up the answer" if you get stuck.

Answer (score 5):

You can compare key lengths for the same algorithm. Between algorithms it does not make too much sense.

If the algorithm is any good (and it would be very hard to prove that for something homegrown), then it gets more secure with a longer key size. Adding one bit should (again, if the algorithm is good) double the effort it takes to brute-force it (because there are now twice as many possible keys).

The more important point, though, is that this only works for "good" algorithms. If your algorithm is broken (i.e. it can be decrypted without trying all the keys because of some design flaws in it), then making the key longer probably does not help much.

If you tell me you have invented an algorithm with a 1024-bit key, I have no way to judge if that is better or worse than a published 256-bit algorithm (I'd err on the safe side and assume worse).

If you have two algorithms in your competition, telling the judge the key size is not helping them to decide which one is better.

Answer (score 2):

Oh man, this is a really difficult problem. One is for sure - key length shows **nothing** about encryption algorithm strength.

I can only think of two measures of encryption algorithm strength:

- Show your algorithm to professional cryptanalyst. Algorithm strength will be proportional to the time cryptanalyst has taken to break your encryption.
- Strong encryption algorithms makes encrypted data look pretty much random. So - [measure randomness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474382/a-good-and-simple-measure-of-randomness) of your encrypted data. Algorithm strength should be proportional to encrypted data randomness degree. 
  **`Warning - this criteria is just for playing arround, doesn't shows real encryption scheme strength !`**

So real measure is first, but with second you can play around for fun.

Answer (score 2):

"Bits of security" is defined by NIST (National Institute of Standards and Technology), in:
NIST SP 800-57 Part 1, section 5.6.1 "Comparable Algorithm Strengths".

Various revisions of SP 800-57 Part 1 from NIST:
http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/PubsSPs.html#800-57-part1

Current version:
http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-57/sp800-57_part1_rev3_general.pdf

The "strength" is defined as "the amount of work needed to “break the algorithms”", and 5.6.1 goes on to describe that criterion at some length.
Table 2, in the same section, lays out the "bits of security" achieved by different key sizes of various algorithms, including AES, RSA, and ECC.

Rigorously determining the relative strength of a novel algorithm will require serious work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the algorithm is sound and that it uses the entire key range...

Raise the number of unique byte values for each key byte to the power of the number of bytes.

So if you are using only ASCII characters A-Z,a-z,0-9, that's 62 unique values - a 10 byte key using these values is 62^10.  If you are using all 256 values, 0x00 - 0xFF, a 10 byte key is 256^10 (or 10 * 8 bits per byte = 2 ^ 80).

Answer (score 0):

My quick and dirty definition is "the number of bits that AES would require to have the same average cracking time". You can use any measure you like for time, like operations, wall time, whatever. If yours takes as long to crack as a theoretical 40-bit AES message would (2^88 less time than 128-bit AES), then it's 40 bits strong, regardless of whether you used 64,000 bit keys.

That's being honest, and honestly is hard to find in the crypto world, of course. For hilarity, compare it to plain RSA keys instead.

Obviously it's in no way hard and fast, and it goes down every time someone finds a better crack, but that's the nature of an arbitrary "strength-in-terms-of-bits" measure. Strength-in-terms-of-operations is a much more concrete measure.