# Is it possible to prove, if a sequence is random?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, random, heuristics

Consider following inputs:

`1,1,2,3,5,8` - it isn't random

`2,4,8,16,32` - this neither

`4,1,2,11,5,9`- this one looks like random-sequence

I would like to ask if is there such algorithm to prove if input is random or it isn't?

Comment: Please define "random" :D

Comment: @Nicolas: see Knuth's *Art of Computer Programming* volume 2, section 3.5 ("What is a random sequence?").

Comment: why did I earn vote down for this question? Is it something wrong?

Comment: @GarethRees I was trying to make OP think about how less _random_ "1,1,2,3,5,8" is compared to "4,1,2,11,5,9" !

Comment: @piotr_dabrowski: I don't think it's worth me downvoting, because I think the question can be (has been) answered anyway. But the problem is that it is an improper use of terminology to say that a sequence "is random" or "is not random". A source of numbers can be random (with a certain distribution and hence a certain entropy) or non-random, and a given sequence of numbers can be the output of a random source or not. But in that case the randomness is not a property of the sequences themselves, rather of how they were generated.

Comment: Actually, I've over-stated that somewhat. If talking about a sequence *in the abstract*, such as "the sequence of results of coin tosses", then one can say that the sequence "is random", meaning that it "is randomly generated". But when talking of a concrete collection of values, one cannot say that `H,H,H` is "more random" or "less random" then `H,H,T`. Of course one could say that `H,H,H` is "less probable" than "two heads and a tail, in any order", but not that it's "less random".

Comment: @SteveJessop: you may want to read Knuth §3.5 too. (To summarize: it does make sense to describe a particular sequence as being "random" or not, and the notion can be precisely defined.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no such prove - if you have perfectly random numbers, the probability of each sequence of length n is equal.
However, there are statistical tests to asses the quality of a random number generator, which is probably what you are looking for. See [Diehard tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diehard_tests).

Comment: It seems that is answer for my question :) From Diehard test this one looks like my favourite one at this moment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_runs_test

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, you cannot *prove* that a sequence was generated randomly or not.  In addition to what @timos [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14321689/387852), it looks like you might have some additional requirements.  It seems as though you desire to ensure that the sequence does not come from some hypothetical list of well-known, "non-random" sequences.  If that is the case, you may be interested in learning of the [On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeisf.org/).

If you have a particular sequence in mind, you can check it against their database.  For instance, `1,1,2,3,5,8` comes up in a number of sequences, but most prominantly in [A000045](http://oeis.org/A000045) (Fibonacci numbers).  A sequence like `4,1,2,11,5,9` does not show up in a search there.

None of this proves anything, but perhaps this is more in-line with your goals in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

I want to emphasize here that the word "random" means not only identically distributed but also *independent of everything else* (including independent of any other choice).

There are numerous "randomness tests" available, including tests that estimate *p-values* from running various statistical probes, as well as tests that estimate *min-entropy*, which is roughly a minimum "compressibility" level of a bit sequence and the most relevant entropy measure for "secure random number generators". There are also various "[randomness extractors](https://peteroupc.github.io/randextract.html)", such as the von Neumann and Peres extractors, that could give you an idea on how much "randomness" you can extract from a bit sequence. However, all these tests and methods can only be more reliable on the first part of this definition of randomness ("identically distributed") than on the second part ("independent").

In general, there is no algorithm that can tell, *from a sequence of numbers alone*, whether the process generated them in an independent and identically distributed way, without knowledge on what that process is. Thus, for example, although you can tell that a given sequence of bits has more zeros than ones, or has no obvious pattern in them, you can't tell whether those bits—

- Were truly generated independently of any other choice, or
- form part of an extremely long periodic sequence that is only "locally random", or
- were simply reused from another process, or
- were produced in some other way,

...without more information on the process. As one important example, the process of a person choosing a password is rarely "random" in this sense since passwords tend to contain familiar words or names, among other reasons.

See also this question: [A Good and SIMPLE Measure of Randomness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474382/a-good-and-simple-measure-of-randomness)