# Is there a good measure for randomness across multiple lists?

Tags: java, random, shuffle

I have the following piece of code :

```
int numberofTimesToRandomize = 10;
long seed = System.nanoTime();
Random r = new Random(seed);
List<List<Integer>> listOfRandoms = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
List<Integer> l = service.get();
for (int i = 0; i < numberofTimesToRandomize; i++) {
    Collections.shuffle(l, r);
    List<Integer> rnd = l.subList(1, 100);
    listOfRandoms.add(rnd);
}
```

What I want to know is whether there is a way to determine the measure of randomness across the 10 lists each of size 100. The size of the list from which the random lists are picked is roughly 10000.

I have seen a couple of questions being answered with "no, there is no way". But those are for sequence of random numbers.
[A Good and SIMPLE Measure of Randomness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474382/a-good-and-simple-measure-of-randomness)

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT :
Based on Peter Lawreys question as to the purpose of this test, I thought one simple measure is to check if the resultant 10 lists are exactly the same *independent of order*.
this question answers that for me : [Simple way to find if two different lists contain exactly the same elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075656/simple-way-to-find-if-two-different-lists-contain-exactly-the-same-elements)

I wonder if this is the only way to unit test the above code.

Comment: You do realize that "numberOfTimesToRandomize" is a ridiculous idea, right? If you shuffle a deck of cards (or a Collection) twice, it doesn't make it twice as random.

Comment: A random sequence has an equals chance of being 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 as any other sequence. What is the reason you want this test?

Comment: Quoting the first answer to the question you linked to "I think what you need to do is identify the aspects of randomness that are important to you- distribution, distribution of digits, lack of common factors, expected number of primes, fibonacci and other "special" numbers etc. "

Comment: @Kayaman - I am not sure I follow you. What I am intending through the variable numberOfTimesToRandomize is that I would like to generate a List of "numberOfTimesToRandomize" lists each of which are random.

Comment: @Lawrey - one purpose is as a unit test to make sure that the lists are at least random. In other words I am not producing the same list every time. Perhaps thats a good measure. If the lists are not the same then there is some randomness.

Comment: You need to copy `rnd` before adding it to `listOfRandoms`, or else you're going to get `numberOfTimesToRandomize` references to exactly the same list with exactly the same elements.

Comment: @Wasserman - turns out that in my testing the result is as you predicted. However, I am not sure I understand why. List<Integer> rnd is a new reference every time and l.subList should return a different slice of the List every time every time.